# Update Microsoft Edge browser via command line

Tags: ansible, microsoft-edge

My requirement is to update microsoft edge browser on azure windows VM using ansible.
I tried below ansible code which worked perfectly

```
win_chocolatey:
    name: microsoft-edge
    state: latest
    ignore_checksums: yes
```

But due to security constraints I am not allowed to use win_chocolatey module as it connects via internet to chocolatey.org

Is there any alternative command line which can update edge automatically via ansible script

I tried using below command but its failing
[image]

Comment: Download the chocolately package from somewhere there is internet connection, and copy that to the target host, then install it.

Comment: They don't recommend to use chocolatey site. The VM has internet but automatic edge updation doesn't happen

Comment: Exactly, then download the package from a trusted source, or ensure the package is available somewhere in your local network. This isn't an Ansible problem.

Comment: I would like to know if there is any alternative command line for updating edge like using "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\EdgeUpdate\MicrosoftEdgeUpdate.exe"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

win_package is the ansible module that you could use. Check out the correct parameters you need and set these in the arguments attribute of the module. And you can chose between internet or ansible controler as the package source.